# request method view to controller not working in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i am getting value of `wallet` and `refer` from form with `$request->wallet` and `$request->refer` i am getting only the value of wallet not refer route is a `POST route`. i have also added csrf but not working

**code for controller**

```
$acc['wallet'] = $request->wallet;
$acc['balance'] = 0;
$acc['uqid'] = rand(10000000,99999999);
$acc['ref'] = $request->refer;
$ck = Account::where('uqid', $acc['uqid'])->first();

if(isset($ck))
{
     $acc['uqid'] = rand(10000000,99999999);
}
Account::create($acc);
```

**View:**

```
@if(session('CurrentAccount')=='')
<form id="checkForm">
   @csrf
   <input type="text" class="wallet-input" name="wallet" placeholder="Your Address...">

   <input type="text" class="wallet-input" name="refer" value="{{ app('request')->input('ref') }}">
   <button type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
@endif
```

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).on('submit','#checkForm',function(event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"{{route('account.check')}}",       
        data: new FormData(document.getElementById('checkForm')),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data)
        {
          console.log(data)
          if(data==99)
          {
            $.notify({ allow_dismiss: true,title: "Sorry!",message: "Invalid" }, { type: 'danger' });
          }
```

Comment: `$request->refer` will come from the value of your `refer` <input>, which is set to `app('request')->input('ref')`.  So where does that come from?

Comment: from url by prepopulating

Comment: What does that mean? Show us the code, show us an example.

Comment: let me explain. i have page where form has two input . one name wallet and other name refer. wallet is filled by manually entering the value while refer is filled by referal url

Comment: So if `refer` is empty, your referral URL is empty.  If it is not, you need to show us the code that sets it, so we can find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `value` attribute id not getting a proper value from request.

Specifically check  if `{{ app('request')->input('ref') }}` is getting any value in : 
`<input type="text" class="wallet-input" name="refer" value="{{ app('request')->input('ref') }}">`

Secondly inside controller :

```
$account = Account::create([
    'wallet' = $request->input('wallet'),
    'balance' = 0,
    'uqid' = rand(10000000,99999999),
    'ref' = $request->input('refer'),
    'uqid' = Account::where('uqid', $acc['uqid'])->exists() ? rand(10000000,99999999) : null

]);
```

(assuming you have these columns in `$fillable =[]` array in `Account` model)

Check into [network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/) of your browser to see what data you are posting. If there is no value for input then controller will not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead** of

```
$request->wallet;
$request->refer;
```

**changes** to

```
$request->get('wallet');
$request->get('refer');
```

Comment: i am getting wallet not getting refer

Comment: If you want to get refer it's same like ....... $request->get('refer');

Comment: acha main check krta hu

Comment: share the complete function including functionName with arguments

Comment: bhai tusi fb te a k madad kr sgde o plz

Comment: I am busy now, and available after 2 PM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188401/discussion-between-inzamam-idrees-and-waqar).

Answer (score 0):

When you need to create uuid, use a helper function you got in laravel **Str::uuid()**, and you don't need to query your db to make sure it didn't exist before.

especially that it can *still be duplicated* with the code you have now.

and you didn't define the new account object.

```
$acc = new App\Account;
$acc->wallet = $request->wallet;
$acc->balance = 0;
$acc->uqid = Str::uuid();
$acc->ref = $request->refer;

$acc->save();
```

and the form method and action are not defined:

```
@if(session('CurrentAccount')=='')
<form id="checkForm" action="{{ route('method/route') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <input type="text" class="wallet-input" name="wallet" placeholder="Your Address...">

   <input type="text" class="wallet-input" name="refer" value="{{ app('request')->input('ref') }}">
   <button type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
@endif
```

Comment: i don't want to make changes any other solution plz bhai

Comment: I updated my answer, check the update and try it alone first

Comment: its using ajax for form

Comment: well, please provide all details we need to know, anyhow, I suggest you inspect the AJAX request from your browser and make sure its sent correctly.

Comment: i am updating question plz check

Comment: from chrome/firefox press ctrl + shift + I, this will open devTools. select network, and submit the form, when the request fired please share its content here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188404/discussion-between-ahmed-nasr-and-waqar).